# #Unable to fetch the data from table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to get the data from db using hibernate, i'm getting empty list. But data is present in table and SQL log printed by the hibernate, if i will fire in DB then i'm getting result.

Note:- I'm using hibernate 5.2.2 and hiberante-jpa will be 1.0

Comment: did you apply the commit in the table??

Comment: yes, i commit in table